# Can find tell me if no files exist?

Tags: find

On my FTP server, I look for files delivered in the past day and remove in-place header & trailer records.

```
find .  -type f -name "CDC*" -ctime -1 -exec sed -i'' -e '1d' -e '$d' '{}'  \;
```

This works well.

I want to automate this in a script. But how can I send myself an email notification is no files are found? I am thinking of doing something like:

```
find .  -type f -name "CDC*" -ctime -1 -exec sed -i'' -e '1d' -e '$d' '{}'  \;
EXIT=`echo $?`
case $EXIT in
0) ...do stuff...
*) mail....exit
esac;;
```

There has to a better way, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you could take whatever command you need to do the search, and pipe a `wc -l` on to the end of it. Then use an if statement to check for zero. So using your example above.

```
NUMLINES=`find .  -type f -name "CDC*" -ctime -1 -exec sed -i'' -e '1d' -e '$d' '{}'  \ | wc -l`

if [ "$NUMLINES" -eq 0 ] ; then
foo
fi
```

Or something like that. I didn't check if that syntax is correct though. But i'm sure you get my drift

Comment: This could work. I need to figure out all possible scenarios. Thanks!!

Comment: yeah it should just do the trick. All you need is the specific find that exhausts all cases and you are golden!

Comment: Came up with this
``RETVAR=`find .  -type f -name "CDC*" -mtime -1 -exec sed....` 
if [ -n "$RETVAR" ] then ...do this...else...do that...fi``
Does the trick.